# Reference request: definition of $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$.

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In this [note](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pde_notes.pdf) on PDE, which is based on Evans's Partial Differentail Equations, it is said that the range of the trace map on $H^1(\Omega)$ for a smooth domain $\Omega$ is $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$. Could anybody come up with a reference regarding a precise definition of $H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$ and the result why it is the range of the trace map?